# About poles of sum of functions

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

I'm following Palka's Introduction to complex function theory, and in page 318 he states the theorem:

> If neither of two functions $f$ and $g$ have worse than a pole at $z_0$ then $f+g$ doesn't have worse than a pole at $z_0$.

My question is, can we know the exact order of the pole of $f+g$ at $z_0$ by finding it's order at $f$ and $g$ separately?

This question came while studying the function $h(z)=f(z)+g(z)=\frac{z^2}{\exp(z^5)-1} - \frac{1}{z^3}$. Studying $f$ and $g$ separately I found that both have poles of order 3 at $z_0$, but I found it much harder to study the pole when $h(z)$ was written as $h(z)= \frac{z^5 -(\exp(z^5)-1)}{({\exp(z^5)-1})z^3}$.

Comment: Sure; add the Laurent expansions.  This certainly may be easier.  That's why we use partial fractions.

Comment: @saulspatz so if $f$ and $g$ have poles of order $n$ the pole of $f+g$ is at worst $n$ and less than $n$ if the terms of the singular part of their laurent expansions cancel out?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @saulspatz great, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is in the theorem below. But first a few lemmas.

**Lemma 1.** Let $a \in \mathbb{C}$, let $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be an open set such that $a \in D$, and let $f : (D\setminus\{a\})\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic. Then $f$ has a removable singularity at $a$ iff $\lim_{z\rightarrow a}(z-a)f(z) = 0$.

**Proof.** This is part of [Riemann's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Removable_singularity&oldid=1036048191#Riemann%27s_theorem). $\square$

**Lemma 2.** Let $a \in \mathbb{C}$, let $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be an open set such that $a \in D$, let $f : (D\setminus\{a\})\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic, and let $m \in \{1,2,3,\dots\}$. Then $f$ has a pole at $a$ of order $m$ iff the limit $\lim_{z\rightarrow a}(z-a)^mf(z) \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ (in particular, the limit exists).

**Proof.** Use a similar proof to the one given to Theorem 2.4 on p. 317 of *An Introduction to Complex Function Theory* by Bruce P. Palka (Springer, 1991). $\square$

**Lemma 3.** Let $a \in \mathbb{C}$, and let $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be an open set such that $a \in D$. For every $m \in \{1,2,3,\dots\}$ the following statement holds: every holomorphic $f : (D\setminus\{a\})\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ satisfying that $\lim_{z\rightarrow a}(z-a)^mf(z) = 0$ (in particular, the limit exists), either has a removable singularity at $a$, or, if $m > 1$, has a pole of order $< m$ at $a$.

**Proof.** We proceed by induction on $m$.

*Base case: $m = 1$.* The conclusion follows from lemma 1.

*Inductive step.* Assume the claim holds for some $m \in \{1,2,3,\dots\}$. Let $f : (D\setminus\{a\})\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic and suppose it satisfies that $\lim_{z\rightarrow a}(z-a)^{m+1}f(z) = 0$ (in particular, the limit exists).

Define the function $g:(D\setminus\{a\})\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ as follows: $g(z) = (z-a)^mf(z)$.

Then $\lim_{z\rightarrow a}(z-a)g(z) = \lim_{z\rightarrow a}(z-a)^{m+1}f(z) = 0$. Therefore, since $g$ is holomorphic (being the product of two holomorphic functions), lemma 1 implies that $g$ has a removable singularity at $a$. Hence, in particular, the limit $\lim_{z\rightarrow a}(z-a)^mf(z) = \lim_{z\rightarrow a}g(z)$ exists and belongs to $\mathbb{C}$. Denote this limit by $L$.

If $L = 0$, the desired conclusion follows from the inductive hypothesis; otherwise, the desired conclusion follows from lemma 2. $\square$

**Theorem.** Let $a \in \mathbb{C}$, let $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be an open set such that $a \in D$, and let $f, g : (D\setminus\{a\})\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic functions such that $f$ has a pole of order $m$ at $a$, and $g$ a pole of order $n$ there, with $m, n \in \{1,2,3,\dots\}$. Then

1. If $m\neq n$, $f+g$ has a pole of order $\max(m,n)$ at $a$.
2. If $m = n$, $f+g$ either has a removable singularity at $a$ , or has a pole there of order $\leq m$.

**Proof.**

Define $F = \lim_{z\rightarrow a}(z-a)^mf(z)$, and $G = \lim_{z\rightarrow a}(z-a)^nf(z)$. By lemma 2, $F$ and $G$ are well-defined and belong to $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.

1. Assume w.l.g. that $m < n$. Then
   $$
   \begin{multline*}
   \lim_{z\rightarrow a}(z-a)^n\big(f(z)+g(z)\big)\\
   = \lim_{z\rightarrow a}(z-a)^{n-m}\lim_{z\rightarrow a}(z-a)^mf(z) + \lim_{z\rightarrow a}(z-a)^ng(z)\\
   = 0F+G \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}.
   \end{multline*}
   $$

   By lemma 2, $f+g$ has a pole of order $n = \max(m,n)$ at $a$.
2. We have
   $$
   \begin{multline*}
   \lim_{z\rightarrow a}(z-a)^n\big(f(z)+g(z)\big) \\= \lim_{z\rightarrow a}(z-a)^mf(z) + \lim_{z\rightarrow a}(z-a)^ng(z)\\
   = F + G.
   \end{multline*}
   $$

   If $F + G = 0$, the desired conclusion follows from lemma 3; otherwise, from lemma 2. $\square$

Comment: You put in a lot of work on a years old question for which the OP noted in the comments that their problem was solved. (The question should have been answered or closed then.) To be really helpful, work on new questions.

Comment: @EthanBolker: What an inane thing to say. This website is like Wikipedia. Posts have no expiration date. People often read posts that are of interest to them years after they posts were written. How do you think I found this question?